# Flat Yorkshire Pudding

Tags: yorkshire-puddings

Why does my Yorkshire Pudding always flatten within minutes after I remove it from the oven? I always use a very hot oven and make sure the batter is at room temperature befor I put it in the oven. It rises beautifully in the oven but falls as soon as I take it out.

Comment: Hello Christin and welcome! Do you mean they totally fall flat or that they 'fall' in the center?

Comment: Undercooked, no other reason.

Comment: I agree with Doug ... you have to cook it so that the batter properly sets up so it'll hold its shape as it cools (when it no longer has the pressure from the steam pushing out)

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that you said 'minutes after' before you said 'as soon as I take it out'.

If it's as soon as you take it out, it's a problem with it being undercooked.

If it takes a few minutes to deflate, it can be an issue with cooling them too quickly.  You can get around this problem by taking a sharp knife or skewer and poking a couple of holes in the top of each one.

This will allow any built up steam to escape (which will unfortunately cool it off), but it will prevent the trapped air from creating a vaccuum as it cools, causing it to collapse.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's possibly undercooked as the comments say it is also possible that there may be too much moisture in your oven for your puddings to set. If they can't set and crystallize they won't hold their structure and they will sink.

Try this: once they get to the top of their rise open the oven for 10-20 seconds to let the moisture. Then close and cook them until golden.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's undercooked, it did happen to me once. I was also told that when they come out of the oven and start to flatten put them back in the oven. I've never tried it as mine have been good but I wonder if anyone else has tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I cook them until they have risen, then turn off oven leaving puddings in oven until they cool. Works every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what you are doing wrong.  An infallible way to make yorkshire pudding is below.  This is assuming you are making it as part of a roast dinner in an electric double oven:

- When the roast is ready to stand, take it out and put everything else (potatoes, vegetables, stuffing) in the top oven.
- Turn the oven up to full, place an oven tray on directly on bottom of the oven (not the bottom notch, resting on the bottom) and put a metal baking tray with some oil in on that.
- Prepare the batter, something like 1 Kg/liter of equal quantities of plain flour, milk and eggs.  Mix them together quite vigorously.
- When the oil is hot enough add the batter to the oil. Shut the oven, and do not open it again until you are ready to serve.
- Make the gravy, lay the table, and get everyone sat down and serving themselves.  This should take about 15 - 20 minutes.
- When everyone is getting close to starting eating, take the yorkshire pudding out of the oven.  At this point is is roughly the size and shape of the oven.
- Bring it to the table, and everyone is impressed.

Answer (score -1):

The most important factor to consider is using all-purpose flour, *not* self-rising.